# How to find the normal plane from a tangent plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{4} +\frac{y^2}{9} +\frac{z^2}{25}=3 $$

I found the tangent plane from this surface at $P(2,3,5)$ by using the gradient vector, $\nabla F=\langle f_x, f_y, f_z\rangle$. I was wondering if I could find the normal plane at that same point using the information already given.

The tangent plane is $(x-2)+2/3(y-3)+2/5(z-5)=0$

The missing key is to find the vector that is perpendicular to the normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a little bit confused -- in three dimensions, a surface has a tangent plane and a normal line. The normal line is spanned by the gradient.

Comment: I want to find the plane perpendicular to the tangent plane--this means the plane that encompasses the normal line that is also parralel to the gradient

Comment: Looks something like this: http://www.dqube.it/ortho/images/stories/articoli/53/fig3.png

Comment: @John Finding what you're describing requires additional information: The input of a vector ($k$ in your picture) in the tangent plane. The normal plane $N_k$ is spanned by $k$ and the normal vector.

Comment: OR The equation of the curve containing point P and on the surface must be given, right?

Comment: @John Yes, that amounts to the same thing since the derivative of the curve at $P$ will be a tangent vector.